irrigation plumbing fix
I heard a big bang when I opened my irrigation valves. I saw a lot of water standing in the valve box so I started digging and this is what I found.
The T that connects the pipes that go to two different zones was busted.
I haven't done PVC piping before but I'm confident that I should be able to fix this. First picture shows where I think I need to make cuts.
questions I have:

Should I use schedule 80 PVC?

if the rest of the PVC pipes are not sch. 80 (which I believe they are not given the existing pipes are white and not gray), does it matter if I use sch. 80 for my repairs? is it even possible?


is it recommended that I replace more of the pipes or can I get away with only fixing the area that I'm going to cut?


